# SSL Certificate Valid on Site not Starting "www" But Invalid on Site Starting With "www"

Tags: powershell, iis, ssl-certificate

I have a site hosted on a remote server on IIS that has two 'https' bindings that are secured with the same SSL certificate. The first binding is https://example.local.com and the second https://www.example.local.com.
On my local pc I have added the site (`1.1.1.1 example.local.com www.example.local.com`) to the Hosts file and added the certificate to the Trusted Root Certificates Authorities location.

When creating the certificate, this is the command that I ran on powershell,

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName "*.local.com","www.*.local.com" -FriendlyName "local_iis_cert" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10) -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 2048
```

The issue is that when I load the site without the 'www' the result is ok:

[image: https://example.local.com]

But when i load the site with the 'www' the result is an insecure site.

[image: https://www.example.local.com]

When i click on the certificate and check the details, I can see that the subject value is:

```
CN=*.local.com
```

and the value under the Subject Alternative Names is:

```
DNS Name=*.local.com
DNS Name=www.*.local.com
```

I would guess a simple alteration to the certificate creation command would solve this problem that I am having but I don't know for sure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you guessed, this issue is happening because of the certificate.
If you want to secure both *local.example.com* and *[www.local.example.com](http://www.local.example.com)*, you'd need to issue the certificate with the following:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName "*.local.com","*.example.local.com" -FriendlyName "local_iis_cert" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10) -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 2048
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible to create a certificate that can secure www.*anything*.local.com, however you can include multiple subdomains if you wish by specifying additional *.*subdomain*.local.com.

[RFC6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#page-27) details the following:

> If a client matches the reference identifier against a presented
> identifier whose DNS domain name portion contains the wildcard
> character '*', the following rules apply:
>
> 1. The client SHOULD NOT attempt to match a presented identifier in
>    which the wildcard character comprises a label other than the
>    left-most label (e.g., do not match bar.*.example.net).

The wildcard character ***MUST*** appear at the very start (left most part) of the DNS name part.